# Passing control information between client-server in socket programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp

I am coding for a server-client programming in C using socket API where I am trying to send control information to client for using different TCP connection. 
Whenever the server has created new socket(TCP), I want it to notify the client to use the new socket for further communication.Currently I have thought of sending UDP packet to the client to be notified. Once the client receives the packet, it sends back the ACK to the server and at the same time switches to the another TCP connection.
I want to know, is there a better to communicate the control data across the network besides using UDP as it is unreliable.Thnx

I would like elaborate on what I am trying to achieve. I am going to measure the parameters like bandwidth,latency, receive window etc. as metric for a Ipv4 and IPv6 TCP connection. Based on the observed performance I will be switching between the two protocols whoever provides better performance.Once the decision is made to switch , I have to notify the partner(may be client or server based on type of bandwidth I am measuring upload, download). I start with IPv4 connection and at the same time open another connection - IPv6 for measuring the bandwidth and latency.

If the IPv6 connection provides better performance, I need to tell the client to switch to IPv6. In this case both the connections are open for monitoring the bandwidth periodically to decide on switching. So I have two queries on this aspect. 1.Is it a good idea to keep two connections at a time.I can create the other connection only when I need to measure the metric as the path followed between two machines will hardly change.If yes, I can pass the control information using the other TCP connection to tell the client to switch. In this way I can also measure the bandwidth and notify client

It it is not a good idea two have two TCP connections, I can use UDP to send the control information. I am avoiding to send control information on the conn used to transfer actual data as it will be an overhead. My code will work like a middleware for transfer the data, where the application will call my functions/macros to transfer the data, and the internal code will take care of measuring the bandwidth and decision to switch.I hope I am clear on what I want achieve. Thank for your feedback in advance

Comment: How does the server communicate with the client before switching? Do they already have an existing TCP connection open? Maybe you should explain more about the architecture -- this question leaves a lot to the imagination.

If you already have an open TCP connection, you can communicate using that. If you are talking to a new client that you haven't seen before, UDP might work but to cope with the unreliability, consider waiting for the ACK and if not received in a few seconds, re-sending it.

Comment: Sounds like re-implementing the FTP protocol?

Comment: Just to add. When I am sending the actual data on any connection , say IPv4 , I will be measuring the bandwidth too using the same data for that connection.The other conn will then send same amount of data for bandwidth measurement so that both the values, viz one for Ipv4 and the other for IPv6 are comparable. Here by bandwidth I mean throughput though there are other techniques to measure bandwidth. The idea is to send minimal amount of packets to measure the bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

The normal sequence of operations for a server-side listening TCP socket is:

```
int fd1 = socket(...);  // Create socket - assuming TCP, not UDP
bind(fd1, ...);         // Bind it to a local address
listen(fd1, ...);       // Set it in listen mode

int fd2;

while ((fd2 = accept(fd1, ...)) != -1)  // Accept an incoming connection
{
    ...communicate with client via fd2...
    close(fd2);         // When finished
}

close(fd1);
```

Now, at the point when you get `fd2`, that has a socket <s>with a different local ephemeral port from the port that `fd1` is connected to</s> (correction per [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp)).  There is no need to communicate any specific information back to the client; the TCP/IP implementation deals with that for you.  The client will have a socket that is connected to `fd2`, with a port (probably an ephemeral port) on its machine connected to the server and the server's ephemeral port.

The point is that the completed connection will have a unique 4-tuple of (client IP address, client port, server IP address, server port).

When it comes to the processing, there are various ways of dealing with it.  You can use an iterative server which deals with one request before dealing with any others.  Or you can create a concurrent server in either of two different ways.  One way is with a threaded server where a thread (from a pool, or newly created for each incoming connection) deals with the new request while the main thread goes back to accept new incoming requests.  The alternative is that you create a forking server where the main server process forks and the child process deals with the new connection while the parent process closes the connection and goes back to listening for the next connection request.

Comment: '... with a different local ephemeral port'. No. It is the same as the listening port. No ephemeral ports involved at the server side. Because the 4-tuple is unique, there is no need for a new port at the server side. Otherwise correct.

Comment: thank you. The accept() will have the same kind of connection viz IPv4. Please refer to my above comments for brief problem statement. I am going to implement different threads as against processes(forking) as it shares same address space and easy to communicate between diff threads as this my code will act as middle layer for the applications.

Comment: @user369823: you can edit your own question - and should do so rather than add three fairly full comments explaining what you want to do.